# Subscript Rules and One-Dimensional Arrays

Tags: java

Assume a one-dimensional array named a has been created. What is the subscript value for the last element in the array.

my answer: `a[0]`

Comment: Shouldn't it be a[a.length - 1] since it is the last element?

Comment: Make your question by having some sample code.

Comment: You have no errors, questions, or code. What are you looking for.

Comment: would my answer: a[0] be deemed correct

Comment: I am looking for somebody of more Java expertise-(considering I am a beginner) to verify my answer to this question

Answer (score 4):

```
a[a.length - 1]) will get you the last element.
```

Comment: Not a problem. Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

In Java, just like C, arrays are 0-based indexed.  That is, 0 is the first element, and it goes up to the end.  Java has a convenient length property you can call with a.length, but this gives the total length, thus you must use (a.length -1) otherwise it will be one past the end.